# what is the difference between implicit and explicit data type conversion in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to know differences  between implicit and explicit data type conversion in Oracle sql can anyone help me

Comment: Have a look at this post, it may help you as it has been answered before.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967973/difference-between-implicit-conversion-and-explicit-conversion-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server and implicit conversion of types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297547/sql-server-and-implicit-conversion-of-types)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a *homework* question, now is it?

In any context, an "explicit" type-conversion is one that you expressly call for in your query or source-code: `x = int(y)`.

An "implicit" conversion is one that is *implied.* For instance, if you `update my table set float_field = 1`, a conversion from integer `1` to floating-point `1.0` is "implied." (But, assigning `1.0` to an *integer* field should be an error.)